# How can I train a YOLOv5 Segmentation model with densely populated instances under limited GPU Memory requirements?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, torch, yolov5

I am attempting to train a YOLOv5 Instance Segmentation model on a dataset containing ~2300 images. Each image is 1800x1800 and there are roughly 100-300 object instances per image. These images were generated synthetically using Blender. The hope is that the final model will be able to make real world inferences from this training data. The intent is to use model predictions to retrieve the localization and dimensions (width and height) of detected instances from input images. I am using a workstation PC to perform training which has 2x NVIDIA A5500 GPU (24gb of GPU Memory).

I performed an initial test using YOLOv5's built-in tools on a smaller version of the dataset using only ~500 images and the results seemed promising. However, after attempting to train on the larger dataset I am unable to perform training, as Cuda appears to run out of GPU memory before even one epoch can begin. I have tried reducing my batch size all the way down to 1, I have lowered the image size parameter to as low as 512, and I have tried using distributed GPU training to no avail. I am uncertain as to why the size of the dataset would impact the training memory usage, as it is my understanding that the memory utilization should be a function of the model size, the batch size, and the size of a single image. I have run this both in a custom Conda environment as well as in the official YOLOv5 Docker container and both are suffering from this issue.

The closest thing to a working solution I have arrived at is writing a script that reruns the YOLOv5 training script on smaller subsections of the data one epoch at a time. This is immensely slow however, and does not seem like a workable solution should my dataset size increase further in the future.

For cost reasons it would be preferable to run training on this machine, and we cannot afford another GPU at this time. The dataset is also privately owned and therefore cannot be shared publicly.

From what I can tell the only difference between my first successful training attempt and these failures is the number of training data points. I am generating my polygons from Blender by automating the random placement of objects within a scene, rendering each placement, and outputting a segmented image mask using pass index information. I then use OpenCV's `findContours()` method on each instance mask with the `CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` method to retrieve the effective polygons. I've read somewhere that the number of instances in a data point can also affect memory usage. Is it possible that in my larger dataset there are simply more images with higher instance counts which weren't present in the smaller dataset? Additionally, is it possible that my polygons are too high resolution and therefore requiring too much memory? If this is the case, would using the minimum area rectangle of my contours lower my memory usage? This would still fit within my constraints, as hypothetically the bounding rectangles for each polygon should accurately reflect the width and height of detected instances.

Here is the last training command I used.

```
python segment/train.py --weights '' --cfg models/segment/yolov5n-seg.yaml --data datasets/gen_seg/data.yaml --epochs 150 --img 512 --workers 16 --batch 1 --device 0
```

Comment: It's weird that training set size (as opposed to batch size) should have any effect. Can it be that you're attempting to pre-load your entire training set to GPU? As you wrote that you're unable to even start a training epoch

Comment: @YuriFeldman This may be the case but I'm unsure how to tell. I've edited my question to include the last command I used to try and train the model.

Comment: On what line does the code crash? This is apparently pytorch which should be helpful to debug - the error itself might be pretty indicative, and then e.g. can set breakpoint before crash and see how much memory is available, should give good indication.

Comment: So I've managed to get it to run for a few epochs but it's still spontaneously crashing due to lack of GPU RAM. The line it fails at seems to be the following: `torch\nn\functional.py", line 2982, in binary_cross_entropy_with_logits

return torch.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, pos_weight, reduction_enum)`

Comment: I'd try to see whether the GPU memory usage grows across iterations (it shouldn't, should stay fairly constant after loading network + first batch processing). If yes - probably something keeps references to GPU objects, will need to locate and fix it. If not - maybe there's another process taking memory on the GPU in parallel? (e.g. firefox/chrome do so by default - need to explicitly disable). I think nvidia-smi should show information about gpu usage, there's also nvitop/nvtop